# Data needed for Cadastral Survey in Colorado, USA

Tags: geospatial, download, data

I need points for the Cadastral surveys for my project and I have a hard time find one... It can be anything that  can add to the project such as online, layers, hyperlinks etc...

The project I am working on is on my Forest and I had a project from another forest. He uses the Cadastral Survey points for his forest.  It looked like they use the GPS points on their forest to collect.

I, myself, do not understand what Cadastral Survey is.  I know they came  from the BLM that started this.

My current project is on the Forest on the Pike and San Isabel National Forest and Cirmarron and Comanche National Grasslands.  I am in Colorado.

Thanks